# syntax error: ';' before '{'

Tags: c++, qt, syntax-error

When my qt program I get some errors. Look at the code, I put the errors with the corresponding lines. I am using Qt creator on Windows 10 to make/run this program.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMainWindow::showFullScreen();
    QPixmap p("C:/Users/*****/Pictures/Start_Orb.png");
    ui->label->setPixmap(p);
    ui->label->setFixedSize(400, 400);
    ui->label->show();
}

void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(MainWindow.isFullScreen() && event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape){//syntax error '.' and syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
        MainWindow.close();//syntax error '.' and syntax error: missing ';' before '.'
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I

Comment: If `MainWindow` is a class name, it cannot be followed by `.`, its static methods should be accessed via `::`.

Comment: close() is not static. So MainWindow::close() will not work either. A simple close(); should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MainWindow.isFullScreen()` is an invalid expression since `MainWindow` is a type, not an object.

If `isFullScreen` is a `static` method of the object, you can use `MainWindow::isFullScreen()`. Otherwise, you can use `this->isFullScreen()`.

`MainWindow.close()` must be similarly modified.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following replacement code:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(this->isFullScreen() && event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape){
        this->close();
    }
}
```